# java run services in parallel on the server

Tags: java, concurrency

I  have a service which process a request from a user.

And this service call another external back-end system(web services). but I need to execute those back-end web services in parallel. How would you do that? What is the best approach?

thanks in advance

-----edit

Back-end system can run requests in parallel, we use containers like (tomcat for development) and websphere finally for production.
So I'm already in one thread(servlet) and need to spawn two tasks and possibly run them in parallel as close together as possible.

---

I can imagine using either quartz or thread with executors or let it be on Servlet engine. What is proper path to take in such a scenario?

Comment: Does your service already handle parallel requests? Also your web services most likely already run in a container that supports multiple threads.. Kind of hard to say anything concrete without knowing the big picture, perhaps you could elaborate it a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Threads` to run the requests in parallel.

Depending on what you want to do, it may make sense to build on some existing technology like Servlets, that do the threading for you

Comment: And can I ensure that those servlets will be run in parallel. What if the server decides to run different servlets at the same time. And I would need to run only mine?

Comment: You run servlets in a servlet container like e.g. Tomcat or Jetty. When a request comes in, it gets dispatched to the servlet, which spawns a thread where the work is done. When more requests come in in parallel, more threads are spawned. After the work is done, the servlet container either destroys the thread or puts it into a pool for future re-use.

Comment: But If you have to many thread(servlets) my first task to be run in parallel will be executed let's say first, and the second can be executed last(after all other threads(servlets) will be processed, am I right? So there can be huge latency.

Comment: I guess this is something to figure out in your real-world scenario. The servlets concept works quite well in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to run the tasks in separate threads.

For something like this, I think you should be using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a bounded pool size rather than creating threads yourself.

The code would look something like this.  (Please note that this is only a sketch.  Check the javadocs for details, info on what the numbers mean, etc.)

```
// Create the executor ... this needs to be shared by the servlet threads.
Executor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 10, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new ArrayBlockingQueue(100), ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy);

// Prepare first task
final ArgType someArg = ...
FutureTask<ResultType> task = new FutureTask<ResultType>(
        new Callable<ResultType>() {
            public ResultType call() {
                // Call remote service using information in 'someArg'
                return someResult;
            }
});
exec.execute(task);

// Repeat above for second task
...
exec.execute(task2);

// Wait for results
ResultType res = task.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ResultType res2 = task2.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above does not attempt to handle exceptions, and you need to do something more sophisticated with the timeouts; e.g. keeping track of the overall request time and cancelling tasks if we run over time.

---

This is not a problem that Quartz is designed to solve.  Quartz is a job scheduling system.  You just have some tasks that you need to be executed ASAP ... possibility with the facility to cancel them.

Answer (score 0):

Heiko is right that you can use Threads. Threads are complex beasts, and need to be treated with care. The best solution is to use a standard library, such as java.util.concurrent. This will be a more robust way of managing parallel operations. There are performance benefits which coming with this approach, such as thread pooling. If you can use such a solution, this would be the recommended way.

If you want to do it yourself, here is a very simple way of executing a number of threads in parallel, but probably not very robust. You'll need to cope better with timeouts and destruction of threads, etc.

```
public class Threads {
    public class Task implements Runnable {
        private Object result;
        private String id;

        public Task(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Object getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run id=" + id);
            try {
                // call web service
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                result = id + " more";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO do something with the error
                throw new RuntimeException("caught InterruptedException", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void runInParallel(Runnable runnable1, Runnable runnable2) {
        try {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable2);

            t1.start();
            t2.start();

            t1.join(30000);
            t2.join(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO do something nice with exception
            throw new RuntimeException("caught InterruptedException", e);
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        Task task1 = new Task("1");
        Task task2 = new Task("2");

        runInParallel(task1, task2);

        System.out.println("task1 = " + task1.getResult());
        System.out.println("task2 = " + task2.getResult());
    }
}
```